# Trying to make a basic enemy movement in a pacman game using pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pacman

So I am creating a basic PacMan game in Pygame, and am trying to figure out how to create somewhat 'intelligent' ghost movement. I don't want the ghosts to be too intelligent making the game too hard, but I also don't want them to just be randomly moving, making it easy on the player.

Here is the first part of my ghost class, with the movement method. I am currently messing around with the part where the player is to the left of the ghost. Any ideas on how I could have the ghost move somewhat intelligently? It runs into walls a lot

```
class Ghost(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, x, y, color):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.game = game
        self.image = sprite_sheet('ghost_spritesheet.png').get_image(0, 0, 24, 24)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0

        self.spritesheet_index = 0

        self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.short_delay = 40
        self.long_delay = 1000
        self.move_list = ['none']
        self.direction = ''

        self.color = color


        self.list_of_directions = ['right', 'left', 'up', 'down']

        self.direction_first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()


    def get_direction(self):
        self.direction_second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if self.game.player.rect.x < self.rect.x:

            if self.direction_second_time - self.direction_first_time > self.long_delay: #simply creating a delay to make sure the ghost isn't constantly changing direction

                self.move_list.append(random.choice(['left', 'up', 'down']))

                self.direction_first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()



        if self.game.player.rect.x > self.rect.x:
            self.move_list.append('right')

        if self.game.player.rect.y < self.rect.y:
            self.move_list.append('up')

        if self.game.player.rect.y > self.rect.y:
            self.move_list.append('down')
```

ANY ideas would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Comment: could always go with the ai algorithms used in the original: http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Comment: @ChristianGibbons thanks, but that seems far too complicated for me. I don't need different behaviors based on color, I just want them to move somewhat randomly, but also not completely stupidly (running into walls and such)

Comment: Try the original AI. It isn't that hard (If you have a way to check where walls are relative to the ghost). If you have problems with implementing that AI, just ask here. This question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to change the ghost direction after a specific amount of time.
This might work but most of the times it will happen that the ghost cannot change direction because at that time there's a wall blocking it from going into the new direction.

Another approach is instead to count how many tiles it has moved and at the next intersection, pick randomly one of the possible directions.

This means that you either need a way to know which possible directions you have, or you pick a random one out of the four possible, and if it's blocked you remove it from the current possible choices and pick another one.

Start from there and you'll be able to build the AI that you need.

For example if a ghost "sees" the player, it may start chasing it. For a ghost to see the player, it's necessary that they are on the same row or column, the ghost is moving in the direction where the player is, and there are no walls in between. After a while (which means after an amount of tiles moved), it will revert to random movement.